# How to get my Java program to output the length of the string input

Tags: java, string

I've made a program that breaks a string down into its individual characters and gets it to tell the user the relative frequency of each letter, however I'm struggling on how to get it to produce the length of the string itself(excluding spaces) I have this method :

```
public static int getNumberOfWordsInSentaence(String text){
     return text.split(" ").length;
}
```

Comment: split returns array, so you're returning number of words in string, not number of "non-space" symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to calculate length of the string without spaces you can use:

```
text.replaceAll("\\s+", "").length()
```